# lineplot whit different colour on line. Visualize time-series with

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In my dataframe I have a column for the date, a price-column and a column with a boolean value.
What I want do to is to plot the price against the date. Depending on the boolean value, I would want to change the colour of the plot depending on the boolean value.

This is the result so far, not happy with the orange line
[image: This is the result so far, not happy with the orange line]

I'm not happy with the orange line since this one just being a straight line until the data in the boolean-column becomes true again.
What I would want is to completely get rid of the orange line when it's just being a straight line.

This is what I have done so far:

```
marked_dates = []
marked_prices = []

for Date, Close, InBool in zip(df_contract.Date, df_contract.Close, df_contract.InBool):
    if InBool == True:
        marked_dates.append(Date)
        marked_prices.append(Close)        

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df_contract['Date'], df_contract['Close'])
plt.plot(marked_dates, marked_prices)
plt.xlim((marked_dates[0], marked_dates[len(marked_dates)-1]))
```

Thank you very much!
BR, Filip

Comment: The simplest way is to replace all values that result in a straight line for price with NaN?

Comment: Is this actually a pandas dataframe in the beginning? `df_contract.Date` hints at this. If you provide this structure, it might be easier to achieve what you want directly from this dataframe without a detour through lists and for loops. Since you have a `Date` column, it might be useful to provide a toy dataset.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes, the values for the straight orange lines doesn't have any values. But the are being automatically plotted as straight lines since they are plotted for one time period when True. Then being plotted again further in time. Between this, when False they are automatically connected as straight lines.
Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.T, yeah I have tried this since df_contract is a pandas dataframe. For example I tried to work with seaborn.lineplot and used the built in function hue. Resulted in straight lines all over. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment was to create code based on the understanding that you wanted to color-code price changes with Boolean values. It's in the form of a looping process to draw a line through the lowest unit of the time series and then use the Boolean value to determine the color. Does this meet the intent of your question?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(2020)
date_rng = pd.date_range('2006-07-01','2007-03-31', freq='1W')
val = np.random.randint(90,130, size=39)
bools = [True, False]
b = random.choices(bools, k=39)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(date_rng),'price':val,'bool':b})
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))

for i in range(len(df)):
    ax.plot(df.loc[i:i+1,'date'], df.loc[i:i+1,'price'], color=('C1' if df.loc[i:i,'bool'][i] == 1 else 'C0'))

plt.show()
```

[image]